# createUploadLink of apollo-file-upload not working with credentials

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, cookies, file-upload, apollo-client

I have apollo-file-upload set up and working until I added the credential option so as to accept and have cookies in the browser but it turns out crashing with the cookies set in fireFox and crashes without cookies set in chrome:

**apollo-client**:

```
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client'

const link = createUploadLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  credentials: 'include'
})

const client  = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

**apollo-server**:

```
 app.use(session({
  store,
  name: SESS_NAME,
  secret: SESS_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
    sameSite: 'none',
    httpOnly: true
  }
}))

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    settings: {
      'request.credentials': 'include'
    }
  },
  cors: corsOptions,
});
```

apollo-server responding with the errors:

Unhandled Rejection (Error): Failed to fetch
46 | // Constructs an instance of ApolloError given a GraphQLError
47 | // or a network error. Note that one of these has to be a valid
48 | // value or the constructed error will be meaningless.

> 49 | constructor({
> | ^  50 |   graphQLErrors,
> 51 |   networkError,
> 52 |   errorMessage,

Answer (score 1):

I just worked fine for me.

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache} from "@apollo/client";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";

const link = createUploadLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
    credentials: "include"
})
const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link
});
```

Try to use cookie-parser and add this in your cors options and just set cors to false in apollo-server-express, if you are using it.

```
const corsOptions= {
   origin: "http://localhost:3000" // full uri of client.
   credentials: true // make sure to add this.
}

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/graphql", cors: false });
```

And, dont forget to use graphqlUploadExpress() middleware in your server.
If you want to upload file through graphql refer this [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/) or see [this video](https://youtu.be/-Zx-9BKgTAs).